# Integrate Angular4 with sails

Tags: angular, sails.js

I am building a website of which frontend has to be built on angular and backend on sails. I have installed sails but i am unable to integrate angular properly.
I have installed angular and a folder **app** has been created in my **assets** folder of sails. The **app** folder contains the **app.components** and **app.module** as in angular 4.
Now the problem is that i have created another component and the constructor is not displaying anything on console. I have used console.log in constructor.
**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>my application</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    title = 'app';
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA  }       from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
    import { RegisterComponent }   from     './components/register/register.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent,RegisterComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: '/register'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{ 
    name = 'aizaz';
    constructor() {console.log("diz");}
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your new component in order for it to be constructed

You need to do something like this in your initial component template

```
<div>
  <h1>my application</h1>
  <app-register></app-register>
</div>
```

Comment: I have written this in my layout view but nothing happens

Comment: is the configuration for app.component.ts and register.component.ts right?

Comment: is the templateurl correct in your register component? - it should be something like './app-register.html'

Comment: my views are like register.ejs as i am working in sails and they are in the views folder

Comment: /register is the route i have declared in my routes file for the view register.ejs

Comment: what should i do then?